# Webview iOS problem in recaptcha with Content Security Policy

Tags: php, ios, webview, safari

I recently did a webview on iOS and I have the following problem

> The source list for Contant Security Policy directive 'script-src'
> contains an invalid source: "strict-dynamic". It will be ignored

The problem only persists in Safari browser and webView, can someone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Safari browser [does not support a `'strict-dynamic'`](https://csplite.com/csp/test214/#safari) token. Check the browser console, it should be a warning there:

```
The source list for Content Security Policy directive ‘script-src’ contains an invalid source: ”strict-dynamic”. It will be ignored
```